# Is it possible to check through a browsers (javascript) if a user being controlled by a rtp

Tags: javascript, anti-cheat

I'm currently developing an anti cheat system for my Learning management system web application and i thought it will be useful to detect remote desktop sessions (teamviewer)
I tried a couple of solutions like css media query reduce motion and i even tried to calculate and compare the mouse velocity of each cases but that didn't do the trick .
I would really appreciate your answers !

Comment: get them to enter their verified address and credit card number, cvv etc whilst they are answering and show it clearly whilst they answer, then you may find cheaters are less likely to do rtp ;p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-cheat is tricky, especially on the Web. Because of privacy/security concerns, websites are severely limited on what information they can know about a user's computer, and there is no way to know for sure if the computer is being remotely controlled. Even if you find a reliable way to detect that using the limited set of tools available to JS, it's often trivial to bypass those checks, either by modifying the scripts or the browser itself.

Of course, this is also a problem on native applications, but to a lesser extent.

Comment: Very good point , thank you sir for your answer !